# What does a mechanic do?

Tags: word-request

Suppose my mobile phone has gone bad. So I gave it to a mechanic. So what will the mechanic do with the phone to "make it return to its original state"? What is this process called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's possible, but highly improbable, that a native Anglophone will call someone who repairs cellphones a *cellphone **mechanic***, in American English, we would normally call such a person a *cellphone **technician***. The word *[mechanic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mechanic)* is usually used to refer to someone who repairs large machines rather than small pieces of electronic equipment.

If you give your phone to a cellphone technician, the person will *fix* or *repair* the phone. Those are two names for "the repair process". Sometimes that involves replacing a module or maybe even soldering a connection (rare, because electronic devices are not made to be repaired these days; they're made to have little detachable modules replaced or to have the motherboards replaced because doing anything else takes too much time & costs too much money).

Comment: "because electronic devices are not made to be repaired these days" ...but to throw away and buy a new one because the profit of the selling company would be too little. +1 anyway :)